# Route only forwarded traffic to VPN tunnel

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, raspberry-pi, vpn

I have Raspberry Pi with active VPN(tun0) connection. Here are my routes

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
10.211.1.14     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

I want to use my RasPi as VPN gateway for some local devices on my local network, where VPN software cannot be installed. How to make my RasPi to route traffic from such devices in tun0, but keep routing via normal wlan0 for everything else?